# Plotting fraction of NAs of a data frame

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

Does anyone know how to plot the graphs of figure 23.1 of the [example chapter of Steyerberg's book](http://www.clinicalpredictionmodels.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=start&cache=cache&media=case_study_survival.pdf)?

The R-function is called "na.plot2" and Displays for example the fraction of missing values in data frame. I cannot find the code on the book's Webpage.

Comment: This sort of thing is dead easy to write, and you will waste more time looking for a solution than brewing your own.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to just write it by-hand. I don't have the source data, but this should be a start for you

```
na <- is.na(dat)
fracna <- colMeans(na)
fracnaper <- lapply(na, function(i) colMeans(na[na[, i], -i]))

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
barplot(fracna, sideways=TRUE)
barplot(table(rowSums(na), sideways=TRUE)
barplot(fracnaper[, 1], sideways=TRUE)
plot(colMeans(na), sapply(fracnaper, sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found useful the functions `vis_dat()` and `vis_miss()` from the package `visdat`. It gives a direct overview of the number of NAs you have for each variable in your data frame, and includes the variable type. See more details in https://visdat.njtierney.com/